# Function question $f(x+1)$ and $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Given that $f(x+1)-f(x)=4x+5$, $f(0)=6$. Find $f(x)$.

My attempt,

$f(1)-6=5$,

$f(1)=11$

How to proceed then? I've never solve this kind of question before.

Comment: Have you any experience with solving closed forms of linear recurrence relations?  In this case, $a_{n+1}=a_n+4n+5$ with initial value $a_0=6$?  Taking the discrete solution and extending it to all real numbers will suffice to find **one** such function.  In reality though, just knowing $f(0)$ isn't enough information to uniquely determine the function, you would need to know at least one value of $f(x)$ for a representative of each equivalence class of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, e.g. by knowing each value for $x$ in $0\leq x<1$

Comment: What is the intended domain for $f$? Is it $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{R}$ or something else? Are there additional assumptions on $f$, like, for instance, continuity?

Comment: @Mathxx If you found one of these answers helpful, you should probably accept one of them. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of question is called a *functional equation*. First, suppose $f(x)$ is in the form
$$f(x)=ax+b$$
Then you can use this assumption to solve for $a$ and $b$. So
$$a(x+1)+b-ax-b=4x+5$$
$$a=4x+5$$
Which cannot be, since $a$ is a constant. So $f(x)$ must not be of that form. So, instead consider the quadratic form
$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
Then we have
$$a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c-ax^2-bx-c=4x+5$$
$$a(x^2+2x+1)+b(x+1)-ax^2-bx=4x+5$$
$$ax^2+2ax+a+bx+b-ax^2-bx=4x+5$$
$$2ax+a+b=4x+5$$
So now we have a system that we can use to solve for the constants $a$ and $b$:
$$2a=4$$
$$a+b=5$$
Which gives us $a=2$, $b=3$. Now you need to solve for $c$ given that $f(0)=6$, giving us $c=6$, so
$$f(x)=2x^2+3x+6$$
If you have any questions, just ask!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution!

Comment: You are assuming that $f$ is continuous or locally bounded or measurable, but the problem does not state so.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Nevertheless, these functions do satisfy the functional equation.

Comment: @Mathxx No problem! If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\uparrow$! :)

Answer (score 4):

Without further assumptions, there are infinite solutions. You may define $f(x)$ over the interval $(0,1)$ in any way you like, then set $f(0)=6$. The recurrence $f(x+1)=4x+5+f(x)$ allows to define $f$ on $[1,2)$, then on $[2,3)$ and so on. The same recurrence written as $f(x)=f(x+1)-(4x+5)$ allows to define $f$ on $[-1,0)$, then on $[-2,-1)$ and so on.

$$f(x) = 2x^2+3x+6+2017 \sin(2\pi x) $$
is an example of a continuous, non-polynomial solution and
$$ f(x) = 2x^2+4x+6-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor $$
is an example of a discontinuous solution. It is true that
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad f(x)=2x^2+3x+6 $$
as shown in other answers, but that is not enough to fix the values of $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x)$ is a solution and $g(x)$ is a $1$-periodic function such that $g(0)=0$, $f(x)+g(x)$ is still a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can telescope it!

For $x=1$ you have $f(2)-f(1)=9$

For $x=2$ you have $f(3)-f(2)=13$

For $x=3$ you have $f(4)-f(3)=17$

For $x=4$ you have $f(5)-f(4)=21$

...
For $x=k$ you have $f(k+1)-f(k)=4k+5$

If you add all of this together, you get

$-f(1)+f(k+1)=9+13+17+21+\cdots+(4k+5)$

Or

$f(k+1)=f(1)+\sum_{i=1}^k (4i+5)$

Comment: But a function is not fixed by its values over the integers.

Comment: Does using only integers to find f mean that the domain is only fixed over the integers?

Comment: Maybe the intended domain for $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, but the question does not state it.

Comment: It does not matter...  I do not have to use the whole domain to find f even if the domain was real numbers.

Comment: You end up getting the same quadratic @Nilknarf gets by the way if anyone is curious

Comment: Infinitely many even if you assume continuity.  Even assuming that it is infinitely differentiable is not enough.

Comment: I don't think I should delete this because whatever the domain is, it is at least part of the solution.